# Rewrite this code using try-with-resources

Tags: java, io, try-catch, try-with-resources

This code is used to copy an instance through java serialization. It uses the traditional try-catch-finally writing method. Can it be changed to **try-with-resources** form?（The **DeepConcretePrototype** in the code is an ordinary java object）

```java
    /**
     * Clone an instance through java serialization
     * @return
     */
    public DeepConcretePrototype deepCloneBySerializable() {
        DeepConcretePrototype clone = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = null;
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = null;
        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = null;
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = null;
        try {
            //Output an instance to memory
            byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(this);
            objectOutputStream.flush();
            //Read instance from memory
            byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
            objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream);
            clone = (DeepConcretePrototype)objectInputStream.readObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (byteArrayOutputStream != null) {
                try {
                    byteArrayOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (objectOutputStream != null) {
                try {
                    objectOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (byteArrayInputStream != null) {
                try {
                    byteArrayInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (objectInputStream != null) {
                try {
                    objectInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return clone;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use try-with-resources, but it's a little tricky because the success of `read` depends on the success of `write`. One way you can write it is with a nested `try`:

```
public DeepConcretePrototype deepCloneBySerializable() {
    DeepConcretePrototype clone = null;

    try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream)) {
        //Output an instance to memory
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(this);
        objectOutputStream.flush();

        try (ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
             ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream)) {
            //Read instance from memory
            clone = (DeepConcretePrototype) objectInputStream.readObject();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return clone;
}
```

Comment: Actually, closing is entirely unnecessary here, as these streams do not encapsulate real resources. The `flush()` is the only required operation and it’s done manually here anyway. Further, you can use `catch(IOException|ClassNotFoundException e) { … }` though returning `null` on error is a questionable behavior…

Comment: True, I assumed the OP was interested in seeing how to use try-with-resources anyway.